# Display list of pages based on author byline field

Tags: modern-pages, online, highlighted-content-web-part

one tricky question. I have a modern SPO page with an article and all mandatory attributes filled, including author byline field. Than a simple task comes from the management for which I do not have solution yet - Is there a way how to display list of all other related pages (in highligted WP using filtering method, for example) having the same author, among the article? Not currently logged user (e.g. [Me]) and not specific, since that filter option (and CAML query) expect manual imput (specific name). For a page template I want to pre-prepare the WPs and use more automated approach for this one, take the value more systematically.

[image]

Thank you for any hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [PnP Modern Search V4](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/) Web Part to get articles where you can user [Page Token](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/usage/search-results/tokens/#page-tokens) to configure query based on current page field values.

I have tested it with PnP Search web part and it's working fine.

Following would be query which you should configure in PnP Search Result Web Part:

```
{searchTerms} PromotedState:2 Path:{Site.absoluteUrl} AuthorOWSUser:{Page._AuthorByline.email}
```

I have used "**PromotedState:2**" additional filter to just show News Post but you can remove it if you are interested in all the pages. Below is the screen shot for the same.

[image]

On top of that PnP Search Result provide templatization functionality to configure UI what ever you want. See [this](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/usage/search-results/layouts/) for the same.

Comment: ... got an approval for our site, let me test that now!

Comment: Works! By Author & DisplayAuthor, thank you!